# What advantages would cyborgs have over humans?

Tags: biology, technology

In my world, a group of cyborgs took over a planet.  For description purposes, I'm wondering what advantages cyborgs would have over regular humans.

Planet is earthlike, and the technology level is higher than modern technology.

Comment: Wouldn't it all depend on how much better the cyborgs would be than humans? What parts, bio-processes, etc? And the technology level 'higher' than modern could mean just about anything. What specific advances/breakthroughs have taken place?

Comment: Xynozore, welcome to the site.  For the sake of how things work around WB we need a little more information.  Cyborgs unfortunately don't exist in real life. when we go beyond modern tech it may as well be magic often times.  Now if you were to ask "Based on modern technology levels and current experimental science, what cybernetic enhancements would be feasible in the next 100 years"  that would certainly be a great question.  As it stands you are asking us to define things for you without any real parameters.  Check out the [tour] and [help] for some guidance on site expectations.

Comment: @Xynozore, it is considered common courtesy on SE sites to wait a minimum of 24 hours before accepting an answer, to give users in all time zones a chance to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Advantages are basically limited only by your imagination/level of technology. At a minimum I'd say a cybernetically enhanced human could have

- Reduced need for food/water/sleep/air
- Enhanced regenerative abilities; if you aren't using nano technology this could be enhanced durability
- Ability to scrub toxins from their system
- Enhanced strength and speed
- Enhanced communication; this alone could be a huge advantage

On top of that you could have AR features, weapons systems, enhanced senses, whatever you need for your story.